# Import and export LDAP settings from Directory utility

Tags: ldap, directory-utility

Is there a way to import and export LDAP settings in macOS Catalina?

In previous OS versions, when installing a new laptop, we will connect it to our LDAP server simply by copying some files with our settings like:

```
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/ldap_server_fqdn.plist
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Search.plist
```

Since Catalina, this solution doesn't work anymore. We always have to register the configuration/bindings manually.